# Is there an orientable prime manifold covered by a non-prime manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, examples, manifolds

A manifold is called *prime* if whenever it is homeomorphic to a connected sum, one of the two factors is homeomorphic to a sphere.

> Is there an example of a finite covering $\pi : N \to M$ of closed orientable manifolds where $M$ is prime and $N$ is not?

There are no examples in dimensions two or three. If one is willing to forgo the orientability requirement, then there are examples in dimension three. In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2038403?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), Row constructs infinitely many topologically distinct, irreducible (and hence prime), closed 3-manifolds with the  property that none of their orientable covering spaces are prime.

There are examples where $N$ is prime and $M$ is not, such as the double covering $\pi : S^1\times S^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^3\#\mathbb{RP}^3$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are examples analogous to Row's in dimensions $n>2$ which are orientable when $n$ is even. I'll give a bit of motivation for the example at the end.

Consider the action of the group $G= \mathbb{Z}^n\rtimes \{\pm I\}=\{ x \mapsto \pm x+ m, m\in \mathbb{Z}^n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The subgroup $G_{m/2}=\{x,-x+m\}, m\in \mathbb{Z}^n $ is the stabilizer of $m/2\in \frac12\mathbb{Z}^n$. Remove open balls of radius $r<1/4$ about the lattice points $\frac12\mathbb{Z}^n$ to get the simply-connected manifold $V= \mathbb{R}^n -\mathcal{N}_r(\frac12\mathbb{Z}^n)$. When $n$ is even, $V$ admits an orientation which is $G$-invariant. This induces an orientation on $\partial V$. Since $G_{m/2}$ acts as the antipodal map on the sphere of radius $r$ about $m/2$, the quotient $W'=V/G$ will be a manifold with $2^n$ boundary components (corresponding to $\frac12\mathbb{Z}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$) each of which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$. The fundamental group of each boundary component will correspond to some $G_{m/2}$ up to conjugacy. $W'$ has a 2-fold cover $V/\mathbb{Z}^n$ which is homeomorphic to $T^n$ punctured at $2^n$ balls.

Take the $2^n$ boundary components of $W'$, and glue them together in pairs, so that when $n$ is even, the induced orientations get reversed, to get a manifold $W$. For concreteness, let's say that we identify the boundary components corresponding to $m/2+\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $m/2+\frac12^n +\mathbb{Z}^n$, inducing a homomorphism $\alpha_m:G_{m/2}\to G_{m/2+\frac12^n}$. In even dimensions, $W$ will be orientable. Since $\pi_1W'=  G$, and the subgroup of a boundary component corresponding to the coset $m/2+\mathbb{Z}^n$ will be conjugate to $G_{m/2}$, we see that $\pi_1 W = G \ast_{m\in 0\times\{0,1\}^{n-1}} \alpha_m$ is a multiple [HNN extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension) by the isomorphisms pairing the subgroups. Each HNN extension will introduce a new group element $t_m$ along with a relation of the form $t_mG_{m/2}t_m^{-1}=G_{m/2+\frac12^n}$. So we can give a relative presentation for the fundamental group as
$$\pi_1 W \cong \langle G, t_m | t_mG_{m/2}t_m^{-1}=G_{m/2+\frac12^n}, m\in 0\times\{0,1\}^{n-1}\rangle.$$ Note that there is some choice here of subgroup representative up to conjugacy which does not affect the overall group isomorphism type.

The claim is that $\pi_1 W$ does not split as a free product. This follows from the Kurosh subgroup theorem, and will be proved below.

Now suppose that $W$ is a non-trivial connect sum $W= W_1 \# W_2$. Then $\pi_1(W)=\pi_1(W_1)\ast \pi_1(W_2)$ by the Seifert-van Kampen theorem. Since $\pi_1(W)$ is not a non-trivial free product, that means that $\pi_1(W_1)=1$ (possibly after reindexing).

We need to show that $W_1'=W_1\backslash D^n$ is homeomorphic to the $n$-ball, and hence $W_1$ is the $n$-sphere. $W_1'$ lifts to the double cover of $W$ coming from the homomorphism $\pi_1(W)\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is homeomorphic to $T^n \#( S^{n-1}\times S^1)^{\# 2^{n-1}}$ (a non-prime manifold). In turn, $W_1'$ lifts to the universal cover of this manifold which is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (because it is an infinite connect sum of $\mathbb{R}^n$s). Hence $W_1'$ is an $n$-ball by the [Schoenflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations), and we see that $W$ is irreducible and orientable when $n>2$ is even.

Now let's see why $\pi_1 W$ is freely indecomposable. Suppose that $\pi_1 W=A\ast B$. Since $ G < \pi_1 W$ is freely indecomposable, by the [Kurosh subgroup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurosh_subgroup_theorem) $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $A$ or $B$, let's say $A$. Moreover, the group $H=\pi_1 W/ \ll \mathbb{Z}^n \gg$ obtained by killing $\mathbb{Z}^n$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}^{\ast 2^{n-1}}$ since $G/\mathbb{Z}^n\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Thus we see that the image $\overline{A}$ of $A$  in $H$ will contain $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and hence will be non-trivial. Moreover, the quotient $H$ will split as a free product $\overline{A}\ast B$. However, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}^{\ast 2^{n-1}}$ is not a free product, since it has a non-trivial center, a contradiction.

**Motivation**

If a finitely generated group $G$ splits as a free product, then any Cayley graph for $G$ (associated to a finite generating set) has more than one end. If $G< G'$ is finite index, then the Cayley graphs of $G$ and $G'$ are almost equivalent (quasi-isometric), in fact a Cayley graph for $G$ can be obtained from one for $G'$ by collapsing some finite trees equivariantly (this is basically the Reidemeister-Schreier method).
Hence if $G$ has more than one end, so does $G'$.

Now a [theorem of Stallings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups) implies that if a group $G'$ has more than one end, then $G'$ is a graph of groups with finite edge groups. Thus, in this example, we found a manifold whose fundamental group is an HNN extension over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ subgroups, but itself is not a free product. But it has an index 2 subgroup that does split as a free product.

If an $n$-manifold $M$ is a connect sum, and $\pi_k(M)=0$ for $k < n-1$, then a similar argument shows that $\pi_1(M)=A\ast B$ is a non-trivial free product. So any manifold finitely covered by such an $M$ will have fundamental group splitting over a finite group. One can probably find many more examples with such properties. I don't know how to find an example which is a connect sum with simply-connected summands, but finitely covers a prime manifold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will take me some time to fully digest it. First of all, is $\pi_1(\mathcal{O})$ the orbifold fundamental group or the regular fundamental group? Second, I am not that familiar with HNN extensions, so I apologise if this is trivial, but what is the normal subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? Does the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\pi_1(\mathcal{O})$ become normal in the iterated HNN extension?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Your first question is correct about the orbifold fundamental group - I got rid of the intermediate orbifold which is a useful trick to come up with such examples, but does not play a role in the end. Also, the subgroup is not normal: the group is a semidirect product, but there are many lifts of the {±} group. So I've modified the argument to first kill $\mathbb{Z}^n$ before obtaining a similar contradiction. Let me know if you need further clarification or see other mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to expand on your answer, I appreciate it. It's not clear to me why the universal cover of $T^n\#(S^{n−1}\times S^1)^{\# 2^{n−1}}$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even the description as an infinite connected sum of $\mathbb{R}^n$'s is mysterious to me (in part because the universal cover of $S^{n-1}\times S^1$ is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $R^n-0 = R^n\# R^n$. So this holds for $S^{n-1}\times S^1$. Actually, any compact submanifold in the universal cover will live inside a connect sum of finitely many $R^n$s which is just $R^n$ punctured at some points.

Comment: Please let me know if my interpretation of your use of the Schoenflies Theorem is correct. As $W_1$ is simply connected, the manifold $W_1\setminus D^n$ is a submanifold of the universal cover (here $D^n$ denotes the open $n$-ball). As you mentioned above, it follows that $W_1\setminus D^n$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and hence there is an embedding $S^{n-1} = \partial(W_1\setminus D^n) \to \mathbb{R}^n$. By the Schoenflies Theorem, $S^{n-1}$ bounds a ball, so $W_1\setminus D^n$ is a closed ball and $W_1 = S^n$. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Yes, thanks for the correction, I was confusing $W_1$ and $W_1\backslash D^n$. I'll fix that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help explaining the details to me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: In the final paragraph, what do you mean by "splitting over a finite group"? Finding an example where the connected sum is simply connected sounds like an interesting problem, although it is probably much more difficult.

Comment: Splitting over a finite group means as an amalgamated free product or HNN extension over a finite subgroup. See the discussion here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups#Cuts_and_splittings_over_finite_groups